# Which phone configuration is better?

Tags: hardware, ram, processor

I want to buy Moto G4 Plus phone but I am confused as they are giving us two configurations.

1) **3 GB RAM** with Snapdragon 617 **Octacore 1.5GHz** processor and 32 GB ROM

2) **4 GB RAM** with Snapdragon 617 **Octacore 1.5GHz** processor and 64 GB ROM

As I searched it on Google everyone is saying that the combination of RAM and Processor always matters.High RAM and Lower processor or vice versa doesn't give us better performance.

So my question is which configuration is better? why?

Comment: Well generally speaking I would say that more RAM won't hurt. More applications can reside in it without having to be closed / cleared from the RAM so multitasking should be a bit better. However this also depends on how motorola has configured android to use the RAM. The latest example of "more RAM isn't always better" is the [One Plus 3 with it's RAM-Management Issues](http://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-fix-the-oneplus-3s-memory-management-almost-double-the-apps-in-memory/). I doubt that it makes a big difference. Check [the reviews](http://www.androidpolice.com/2016/07/19/moto-g4-review/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enough amount of ram but your first priority must be processor, GPU and chipset .
Of course, Ram should be good for seamless performance .
Go with always snapdragon SOC, for good performance and gaming..
Hope that helps..

My devices:
Moto g
Redmi note 3
One plus 3